# How to configure authentication for Elastic APM using appsettings.json for a .NET app

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-6.0

How to configure authentication for Elastic APM in Elastic cloud using appsettings.json for a .NET 6 console application?

I have the following *appsettings.josn*

How to add authentication here?

```json
  "ElasticApm": {
    "ServerUrls": "https://elastic-test.apm.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com",
    "ServiceName": "net-console",
    "Environment": "Development"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

An Elastic APM **ApiKey** is needed.

Official documentation reference https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-reporter.html

For the Elastic v 8.x

1. In Kibana goto *Stack Management* -> *Security* -> *API keys* and create a new API key there
2. Copy-past this key in the appsettings.json

```json
"ElasticApm": {
    "ServerUrls": "https://elastic-cloud.apm.westeurope.azure.elastic-cloud.com",
    "ServiceName": "example-net-console",
    "Environment": "Development",
    "ApiKey": "...=="
  }
```

This key should not be submitted to the source code repository!